# Why is $\int_\varepsilon^{1/e}-\frac{1}{\\\log(t)}dt = \int_1^a \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\varepsilon = e^{-a} \in [0,e)$, why does the following hold (including $\varepsilon=0$)?

$$
    \int_\varepsilon^{1/e}-\frac{1}{\\\log(t)}dt = 
    \int_1^a \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx
$$

Comment: Are you sure that the limits in the second integral is from $1$ to $a$ ? I think it is from $-a$ to $a$.

Comment: I'm practising last year's exam, so I cannot say for sure. Your derivation makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the substitution $x = -\log(t)$. Thus, $dx = -1/t \,dt \implies dt = -e^{-x} dx.$  Notice that $t=\varepsilon \implies u = a$ and  $t=1/e \implies u = 1$.  Hence, you have

$$\int \limits_{\varepsilon}^{1/e} -\frac{dt}{\log(t)} = \int \limits_{a}^{1} -\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx = \int \limits_{1}^{a} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx.$$

Since $\varepsilon \in (0, e)$, we have $a \in (-1,\infty)$. You shouldn't include $\varepsilon =0$ because the exponential is always positive.

Notice that if $a \in (-1,0]$ the function $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ has a singularity at $x =0$ and the integral diverges. Hence, the equality holds if and only if $a \in  (0, \infty)$.

Comment: My mistake was in the first the integral's upper bound, it should've been: $1/e$. Your substitution is still valid though.

Comment: @Winther, You are right! I will see that.